# Defining bookmarks and aliases in ``ipython_config.py`` configuration file

Tags: ipython

I use IPython 5.1.0 with Python 3.5.2 at the command line on OSX 10.11.6.

I would like to define bookmarks and command aliases to be loaded when I start the IPython interactive shell.

I thought I would be able to run magic commands in the `ipython_config.py` configuration file (such as `%bookmark FOLDERS /Users/tbaker/folders`), but this does not work -- with or without the leading percent sign `%`.

Ideally, I would get these bookmarks from an external file of bookmark lines that is supposed to be shared between `ipython` and `bash` (for which I wrote a `bookmark` function with the same functionality as IPython's `bookmark`).

Nothing I have tried has worked, including an attempt to enclose the magic commands in various wrappers, e.g., `get_ipython().magic(...`.  Indeed, aliases and bookmarks appear to be designed for definition on the fly, at the IPython prompt, and not batch-loaded at startup time.  Does anyone see a way either to define bookmarks in the IPython startup configuration files, or to have IPython fetch the bookmark definitions from another file on startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run configuration commands at iPython startup locate the following line in your `.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`

`c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%alias echo show']`

You can also have a file loaded with a bunch of iPython commands using `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_files = []`

Hope this helps

Comment: For `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_files = []` to work, the files listed there must have the filename extension `.ipy` and the commands must be prefixed with `%`, as in `%bookmark GITHUB /Users/tbaker/github`, even if `c.InteractiveShell.automagic = True`.

Answer (score -1):

```
# Python 3.11.4
# IPython 8.6.0

from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()

define_alias = ipython.alias_manager.define_alias

# %alias lll ls -sh
define_alias('lll','ls -sh')
```

Added comment per request.

Having the same problem of the OP, I've arrived here from a search.

The previous solution didn't work for me. When I found this one, I came back for sharing it.

Note that, if it is written as it is in a configuration script, the defined identifiers will leak in the main context; if you don't want that, you'll have to `del` them after the use or to embed them somewhere else.

Comment: Hi @passerby, welcome to the stack! Please refrain from posting code-only answers, unless they are completely self-explanatory. This question received an accepted, upvoted answer three years ago - please add an explanation to your answer that describes what you are doing and why somebody with this problem might consider your proposed solution.